# Get total hours from Doctrine date range

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to get the total hour for all field(time) base on doctrine 'BETWEEN'.This is exactly the code in the repository

```
  public function findTotalHoursByDateStartDateEnd($from,$to,$user)
{
    return $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->select('t.timein','t.timeout')
        ->where('t.workingday BETWEEN :from AND :to')
        ->andWhere('t.users = :id')
        ->setParameter('from', $from)
        ->setParameter('to', $to)
        ->setParameter('id', $user)
        ->orderBy('t.workingday', 'ASC')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
    ;
}
```

controller

```
  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entity = new Payroll();
    $user = $request->request->get('edgeweb_project_payrollbundle_payroll')['user'];
    $from = $request->request->get('edgeweb_project_payrollbundle_payroll')['start'];
    $to = $request->request->get('edgeweb_project_payrollbundle_payroll')['end'];

    $total_hours = $em->getRepository('EmployeeBundle:Timerecord')->findTotalHoursByDateStartDateEnd($from,$to,$user);
```

With this var_dump function,  I know the method above return the expected values

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["timein"]=> object(DateTime)#456 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "1970-01-01 14:12:20.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(11) "Asia/Manila" } ["timeout"]=> object(DateTime)#446 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "1970-01-01 14:12:27.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(11) "Asia/Manila" } } }
```

But my I am confused how to return only the total hour base on the query above.

Entity

```
   //DateTime
   private timein;

    //DateTime
   private timeout;
```

**Update**

```
  user 1
      **from**(january1)            **to** (january4)
         t/i    t/o                   t/i    t/o
      jan 1 4:00  5:00(1 hrs)        jan 3 4:50: 5:50(1 hrs)
      jan 2 3:50  4:50 (1 hrs)        jan 4 5:00  5:30(30 min)

      total = 3.30(3 hrs 30 minutes)///this is the result I want
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Do you want time in hours between timein and timeout, for each row, or do you want the total time in hours between each row of timein and timeout per user?

Comment: @Richard I want the total time in hours between each rows of time in and time out.